# Create an effect on a text in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, text, fonts

How do I create a text effect like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcIt1.png

I tried different things with the spans etc., but the best result I got was this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RyGA.png.

Could someone help me to recreate this effect from 0 please? I have the right font if needed: Poppins without-serif

Comment: Please show a running version of your code—all `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: Here is my html document: https://bin.readthedocs.fr/kishes.txt
And my CSS document : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/tantem.txt
I didn't want to post my code, because even I have trouble understanding it, I tried different things, I even started several times from 0 but it is mission impossible for this effect.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Thanks, I took the opportunity to upload a version that I started about an hour ago: https://jsfiddle.net/9pusL8v4/

Comment: If you add `display: inline-block;` to `.highlight`, the text will break as one element (like you want) instead of breaking by individual text node.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I'm looking for this result: https://hermesbot.app/
I can re-upload the code I just edited but I'm far from the desired result x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234488/discussion-between-kalypsotek-and-andy-hoffman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the `h1` an `inline-flex` container, pointing its children in a columnar direction. Each `span` inside the `h1` is a flex child and will occupy its own line.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 span {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #221616;
}

body {
  font-family: Poppins,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #26372b;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg,#1c271f,#221616);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="branding">
  <h1>
    <span>The future of</span>
    <span class="highlight">your discord bot</span>
    <span>is on the way !</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```